# localStorage function returning NaNs value

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```
I am trying to display the shortest time taken to click a shape. However the `localStorage` function is returning a `NaN` value instead of the required Number value. How can I tweak the code to return a number value.
```

Thanks

```
document.getElementById("shapes").onclick = function() {

    document.getElementById("shapes").style.display = "none";

    shapeAppearDelay();

    var end = new Date().getTime();

    var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;

    document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = "Time taken: " + timeTaken + "s";

    var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;

    if (localStorage.shortestTimeTaken) {

        if (timeTaken < Number(localStorage.shortestTimeTaken)) {

            localStorage.shortestTimeTaken = timeTaken;
        }

    } else {
        localStorage.shortestTimeTaken = timeTaken;
    }
    document.getElementById("shortestTimeTaken").innerHTML = "Shortest time taken: " + localStorage.shortestTimeTaken + "s";
}
```

Comment: Firstly what does `shapeAppearDelay()` do? - I mean is it relevant or not? Also remember to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` when interacting with local storage. You're currently just adding properties to the local storage object rather than actually storing data within the local storage.

Comment: Where do you define `start` variable? I think there is issue.

Comment: I create a sample and it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/skhe3oow/16/   The only problem i could see is start variable. Make sure it is of type number before any operation else it might return NaN

Answer (score 0):

To set value in the localStorage, please use `setItem`

```
localstorage.setItem("shortestTimeTaken",timeTaken)
```

To get value,`getItem`

```
localstorage.getItem("shortestTimeTaken")
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use `setItem` and `getItem` Please read Basic Concepts from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: @Tanmay  `setItem` and `getItem` is one of the way to handle localStorage and widely used method also.Please go through the Basic concepts from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Right. That's why I'm saying `localStorage.shortestTimeTaken` is also workable instead of `setItem` and `getItem`.  So how this would be the answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

if you are save your shortestTimeTaken value in localStorage you can get data with localStorage.getItem('shortestTimeTaken'). LocalStorage had 2 function setItem('key', 'value') & GetItem('key')

Comment: The syntax of using localStorage from question is also valid. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is by using `setItem()` and `getItem`:

```
...
if (timeTaken < Number(localStorage.getItem("shortestTimeTaken"))) {
    localStorage.setItem("shortestTimeTaken",timeTaken);
}
...
```

Comment: Please read entire link provided by you. The syntax from question is also valid. This is not a issue of `setItem` and `getItem`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API